# check if selection contains div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
t = window.getSelection();

if ((t) contains (div.class)){
 //do something
}
```

How can I do that WHILE selecting the text? Not after the text is selected(eg: after I release the click). I plan to remove selection (document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); ) if I find a div with a specific class.

Thanks!

I already have a mouseup function. if that is what I need, I can add new code to that...

Answer (score 0):

To check if the attribute exists, just use find on your object called "t" and look for any div. If you find something, attribute length will be > 0:

```
if(t.find("div").length > 0) {
    //do something
}
```

If you want to trigger your code before the selection is over you need to use an event that triggers before like mousedown.

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function() { 
    var t = window.getSelection();
    if(t.length > 0) { //This should catch the problem when there is nothing selected
        var obj = t.find("div[class=xy]");
        if(obj.length > 0) { //my div with class xy was found!
            //do something
        }    
    }
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
here:

var obj = t.find("div[class=quoted]");

Comment: `mousedown` will only fire once, when there's no selection yet.

Comment: Ye that is correct, I forgot. We need another event function that is executed when something is selcted... First of all I fixed the uncaught TypeError by checking if the object is valid...